# Why can't firefox play webm when it fails to decode the mp4?

Tags: html, firefox, video, mp4, webm

Firefox -on osx- fails to decode the mp4 file inside the `<video>` tag, and it ignores the webm source completely, when I right click on the video and choose "show video" the webm video plays normally in a new tab!.

**Here is an [example](https://www.heksar.com/posts/show/861) from my website.**

extra info: I'm triggering the play/pause using the html5 video API, it works without a problem in webkit browsers and it is triggered on firefox -since i can listen to the event being fired- but the video doesn't play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I had to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`to my ffmpeg output options in order for the mp4 to be firefox "compatible".